# de Rham cohomology of $S^2 \setminus \{$points$\}$

Tags: homotopy-theory, de-rham-cohomology

As a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183776/homotopy-equivalence-of-mathbbr3-setminus-lines), I'm interested in how to calculate the de Rham cohomology groups of $S^2 \setminus \{$n points$\}$, where $n = 2, 4$ and then for general $n$, using Mayer-Vietoris/Homotopy equivalence/homeomorphism relations.

Is it true that, for $S^2$ with $k$ points removed, the space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $k-1$ points removed? I think I know how to compute the de Rham cohomology groups of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{$points$\}$, so I guess this is more of a verification than asking for an explanation (provided what I wrote above is correct).

Note that if the sphere has 2 points removed, then those points are antipodal to each other (as the points were obtained by having a line strike through the sphere, if you wanted to know where this comes from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove a single point from $S^2$, the remaining space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you remove more than one point, the homeomorphism will map the additional points to points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So yes, a sphere with $k$ points removed is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $k-1$ points removed.

Comment: So, $S^2$ with two points removed is the same as $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one point removed, which is the same as $S^1$, correct?

Comment: On the level of homotopy, yes and that is what you need for deRham cohomology. But $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus one point is not homeomorphic to $S^1$ because homeomorphisms preserve dimension.

Comment: yes, I meant homotopy equivalence. Thank you.